# Why does rails console give different size of relationship than in the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My relationship between posts and comments are showing differently in the rails console and the web server! How could that be? I was confused because a partial was rendering with wrong links, and I thought something else was wrong, but the partial should not have rendered at all because the collection should be empty! I even use an if/else to check the size, and it was still showing the partial for the empty relationship!

Rails Console:

```
irb(main):033:0> p=Post.find(6)
=> #<Post id: 6, title: "Yahoo", comment: "The home page.", link: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2013-10-06 21:53:24", updated_at: "2013-10-07 00:43:25">
irb(main):034:0> p.comments.size
=> 0
```

posts/show.haml:

```
%h2 Comments
Post ID:
=@post.id
, Comment Size: 
=@post.comments.size
- if @post.comments.empty?
  No comments.
- else
  = render @post.comments
```

Browser: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/6`

```
Comments

Post ID: 6 , Comment Size: 1
Commenter:
```

comments/_comment.haml: Doesn't seem relevant...

Rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: Not referred to subject: you could write in HAML something like this: = "Post ID: #{@post.id}, Comment Size: #{@post.comments.size}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a form for new comment somewhere on this page and you build new comment in controller:

```
@new_comment = @post.comments.build
```

That's why @post.comments.count is 1. You could rewrite your code:

```
= @post.comments.reject{ |t| t.new_record? }.count
```

*UPD.*

There is a nicer way to do this thing: instead of adding *reject* method you could add scope in your *Comment* model:

```
scope :saved, where('id is not ?', nil)
```

And then in view:

```
@post.comments.saved.count
```

Comment: Exactly what I was just going to write. I suspect that's whats happening here. As an alternate solution, I would suggest simply instantiating a new comment object if possible (`@comment = Comment.new`), so it doesn't have a reference to the post in the first place.

Comment: Thanks that's it. Did not know what .build does, and I copied/pasted it so didn't pay attention.